# F# use type as a property name

Tags: properties, f#, keyword, names

I need to have class like the following

```
type BubbleChartSeriesDefaults()=
    let mutable _type:string  = "" 
    member t.type  with get() = _type and set v = _type <- v
```

F# does not like me using the keyword type as a property name.
I am sending some f# types down the http pipe to be consumed by a javascript client.
The consumer is looking for a property name called type.
Using a keyword for a property name is not great but, is there any way of sneaking round this.
Anyone know how to get a property called type onto a f# class ?
(Kind of like using @case for variable in c# ...)

Comment: Jack's answer is correct.  Note that if you're using F# 3.0 then you can get rid of the mutable field, too: `member val _type = "" with get, set`.

Comment: cheers, need the mutable though right now...

Answer (score 6):

In F#, you can use anything you want as an identifer (property name, type name, etc.) if you enclose it in double backticks. In your case:

```
type BubbleChartSeriesDefaults()=
    let mutable _type:string  = "" 
    member t.``type``  with get() = _type and set v = _type <- v
```